# ArcGIS 10 Locators: TA_Address_NA_10 vs TA_Streets_US_10 -- which to use?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geocoding

I see there are two locators on tasks.arcgisonline.com, TA_Address_NA_10 vs TA_Streets_US_10. I'm having difficulty understanding the difference between the two.

From browsing the properties it seems that the "Address" locator is a composite which contains a whole bunch of locators, using Rooftop as first and "Streets" second. I'm guessing that Rooftop usually provides the most accurate location for an address. Is that true?

Does it follow that you should always use "Address"? Why would you ever use the "Streets" locator?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Locators/TA_Address_NA_10 (GeocodeServer)** = North America (including Canada)

*Service Description: This locator enables you to geocode street addresses in North America. The locator is a **composite geocoder that supports multiple levels of geocoding**. The following levels of geocoding are supported in the USA: street address point, street address, street name, ZIP Code, ZIP+4, and city/state. The following levels of **geocoding are supported in Canada**: street address point, street address, street name, postal code, and city/province. The locator is based on NAVTEQ 2010 Q4 reference data for North America and is limited to the coverage for the United States and Canada. The locator accepts both single-line and multi-line input addresses. The locator can be used to geocode single addresses, reverse geocode, or batch geocode up to 10 addresses per request. For more information, visit us online. Copyright:© 2011 Esri, NAVTEQ.*

http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Address_NA_10/GeocodeServer

**Locators/TA_Streets_US_10 (GeocodeServer)** (USA Only)

*Service Description: This locator enables you to geocode street addresses in the United States. The locator is **designed to support street address level geocoding only**. The locator can be used to geocode single addresses, reverse geocode, or batch geocode up to 10 addresses per request. The locator is based on NAVTEQ 2010 Q4 reference data for the United States. For more information, visit us online. Copyright:© 2011 Esri, NAVTEQ.*

http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US_10/GeocodeServer

Comment: So the documentation for the former does not specifically mention "US_Rooftop". What is that, exactly? Is it more accurate than the street address geocoder? How is it different to "US_Streets" geocoder which that composite locator also contains? Is "US_Streets" within the TA_Address_NA_10 locator the same as TA_Streets_US_10?

Comment: US_RoofTop: Used for finding latitude and longitude of a U.S. building  http://help.arcgis.com/en/data-appliance/3.1/help/basemap/index_Left.htm#CSHID=na_address_locator.htm%23|StartTopic=content%2Fna_address_locator.htm%23|SkinName=agda